# Random selection for a variable set with a guarantee of every item at least once

Tags: c#, algorithm, random

I am working on a game in c# but that detail is not really neccessary to solve my problem.

At I high level here is what I want:

- I have a set that could have any number of items in it.
- I want to randomly select 10 items from that set.
- If the set has less than 10 items in then I expect to select the same
  item more than once.
- I want to ensure every item is selected at least once.

What would be the algorithm for this?

Sorry I'm not sure if this is an appropriate place to ask, but I've got no pen and paper to hand and I can't quite get my head round what's needed so appreciate the help.

- In addition I might also want to add weights to the items to
  increase/decrease chance of selection, so if you are able to
  incorporate that into your answer that would be fab.

Finally thought I should mention that my set is actually a `List<string>`, which might be relevent if you prefer to give a full answer rather than psuedo code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to randomize an array.  It takes an integer array and randomly sorts that list a certain amount of times determined by the random number (r).

```
    private int[] randomizeArray(int[] i)
    {
        int L = i.Length - 1;
        int c = 0;
        int r = random.Next(L);
        int prev = 0;
        int curr = 0;
        int temp;

        while (c < r)
        {
            curr = random.Next(0, L);
            if (curr != prev)
            {
                temp = i[prev];
                i[prev] = i[curr];
                i[curr] = temp;
                c++;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look for effective code, my answer isnt it. In theory, create some collection you can remove from that will mirror your set. Then select random member of the object from it ...and remove, this will garantee items wont repeat(if possible).

```
Random rnd = new Random();
List<int> indexes = new List<int>(items.Count);

for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    indexes.Add(i);

List<string> selectedItems = new List<string>(10);
int tmp;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
tmp = rnd.Next(1,10000); //something big
if(indexes.Count > 0)
{
    selectedItems.Add(yourItems[indexes[tmp%indexes.Count]]); 
    indexes.RemoveAt(tmp%indexes.Count);
}
else
    selectedItems.Add(yourItems[rnd.Next(0,9)]); //you ran out of unique items
}
```

where items is your list and yourItems is list of selected items, you dont need to store them if you want process them right away

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) the collection and pick elements from the front until you have the required amount.

Once you've gone through all the elements, you should perhaps shuffle it again, so you don't just repeat the same sequence.

The basic algorithm for shuffling: (in pseudo-code)

```
for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
   j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
   exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

With the above algorithm (or a minor variation), it's possible to just shuffle until you reach the required number of elements, no need to shuffle the whole thing.